# Passing Parameters in MS Web Deploy Command Line Deployment

Tags: command-line, msdeploy, webdeploy

I used msbuild to build a deployment package for my website.  I am trying to use the generated deploy.cmd file located in the package to deploy to a remote server.  I am using web deploy's parameters and I would like to set these at the command line using the -setParam flag.

The usage instructions for WebDeploy indicate that I need to enclose the -setParam configuration option in quotation marks because it contains an '=' character.  However, the deploy.cmd file passes the entire option, including quotation marks, to the msdeploy executable.  The msdeploy executable fails to run because the option does not start with the "-" character.

```
Error: Unrecognized argument '"-setParam:TestParam=ABC123"'. All arguments must begin with "-".
```

What do I need to do in order to get the setParam call working with the cmd file generated by msBuild?

Answer (score 1):

Have successfully used `-setParam` option in the following syntax, enclosing entire option in double quotes, and dubling double quotes inside:

```
...deploy.cmd "-setParam:name=""IIS Web Application Name"",value=""example.com"""
```

Comment: I have enclosed all inside quotes, but haven't doubled the quotes.


`MyApp.deploy.cmd /Y "-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="MyApplicationNameinIIS""`. It works too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the entire parameter in quotes because of the equals sign. Just the parameter key and value because it may contain spaces.

```
-setParam:"TestParam"="ABC123"
```

should work for your example. Or in real world:

```
-setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="example.com"
```

Comment: Hi Steven,  that doesn't work, I get: Error: Unrecognized argument '"TestParam"'.  It looks from the output of running the command that the deploy.cmd is removing the spaces from what I pass in.  When I run the msdeploy executable directly, I don't have problems.  It seems that the deploy.cmd produced in the package is mangling the arguments.

Comment: @NotSpecified Have you tried playing with all the escaping characters around the quotes?

Comment: Possibly.  I'm not sure I know all of them, but I tried the options I know.